# MySQL e JasperSoft

Tags: java, mysql, jaspersoft-studio

Preciso gerar um relatório dinâmico através do JasperSoft, fruto da consulta de três tabelas MySQL. As tabelas são:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc`.`Catalogo` (
  `idCatalogo` INT NOT NULL,
  `titulo` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `Autor` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `Editora` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `anoPublicacao` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCatalogo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc`.`Curso` (
  `idCurso` INT NOT NULL,
  `nomeCurso` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tipoCurso` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `vagas` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCurso`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tcc`.`Referencias_adotadas` (
  `idReferencia` INT NOT NULL,
  `tipoReferencia` INT NOT NULL,
  `Titulo` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `Autor` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `Editora` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `anoPublicacao` INT NULL,
  `Disciplina_idDisciplina` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idReferencia`),
  INDEX `fk_Referencias_adotadas_Disciplina1_idx` (`Disciplina_idDisciplina` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Referencias_adotadas_Disciplina1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Disciplina_idDisciplina`)
    REFERENCES `tcc`.`Disciplina` (`idDisciplina`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

A idéia é criar os seguintes campos:

```
Titulo|Autor|Quantidade de exemplares|Vagas|Vagas/exemplares
```

Onde título e autor pego de `referencias_adotadas`. A seguinte consulta, realizada separadamente funciona:

```
SELECT titulo, autor FROM referencias_adotadas
Where idCurso = idCurso(Parâmetro criado no jasper)
```

Quantidade de exemplares busca os títulos e autores na tabela `catalogo` e os contabiliza. O seguinte código, realizado separadamente funciona:

```
select count(*) as 'quantidade de exemplares' from catalogo
where titulo = 'Parametro Jasper' and autor = 'ParametroJasper';
```

Vagas busca a quantidade de vagas por curso:

```
SELECT vagas FROM Curso where idCurso = parametrojasper;
```

E vagas/exemplares é igual ao número de vagas dividido pela quantidade de exemplares.

Estou tendo problemas para gerar uma única consulta que englobe tudo isso. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.